# unable to send emails using emailjs with Angular 4

Tags: node.js, angular

I installed **emailjs** in my project

```
npm install emailjs --save
```

I turned on less secured apps in my Gmail and imported in my ts page as

```
import * as emailjs from 'emailjs';
var server  = emailjs.server.connect({
                  user:    "", 
                  password:"", 
                  host:    "smtp.email.com", 
                  ssl:     true
});


server.send({
   text:    "i hope this works", 
   from:    "", 
   to:      "",
   cc:      "",
   subject: "testing emailjs"
}, function(err, message) { console.log(err || message); });
}
```

I'm getting following

> ERROR: TypeError: connect is not a function

[image]

Comment: Are you trying to send email from the browser?