# I am not able to send email using emailjs in angular

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript

I am using emailjs to send auto generated emails in angular. I am getting the same error which is mentioned in the below link:
[unable to send emails using emailjs with Angular 4](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54059643/11724094)

If anyone has any solution for this then it will be very helpful.

```
import * as email from 'emailjs';
var server = email.server.connect({
  user: 'xyz@gmail.com',
  password: 'xyz',
  host: 'smtp.gmail.com',
  ssl: true
});

server.send({
  text: 'some text',
  from: 'xyz',
  to: 'abc <abc@gmail.com>',
  cc: '',
  subject: 'Greetings'
}, function (err, message) {
  console.log(err || message);
});
```

Comment: Can you please provide the code that produces that error?

Comment: I have added the code that i am using. @AlexisPavlidis

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at https://www.npmjs.com/package/emailjs

It says the following:

> send emails, html and attachments (files, streams and strings) from
>   node.js to any smtp server

Which means that it's server side code and can't be used by angular.

You need to create an api that will be used from front end and in your node js server send the email.

### Api Creation with nodejs

- In order to use nodejs backend (and thus emailjs) you need to follow [this guide](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Server-side/Express_Nodejs/development_environment).
- You can follow [node js api guide](https://www.codementor.io/olatundegaruba/nodejs-restful-apis-in-10-minutes-q0sgsfhbd) to build your api.

Create a new controller that will accept the object

```
{
  text: 'some text',
  from: 'xyz',
  to: 'abc <abc@gmail.com>',
  cc: '',
  subject: 'Greetings'
}
```

and use emailjs in this to send the email.

Comment: Can you please tell me how can i create an api. If you can provide one example for this then it will be good.